# How to move the chevron icon to left in react-native ListItem

Tags: listview, react-native, listitem

I need to move the chevron Icon little bit left in the container. [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. marginRight
2. paddingRight
3. Set a fixed with to the wrapper View on the left